# How to identify whether an item is a file or a folder in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qdir, qfileinfo

I wanted to specify from a path, whether the item is a file or a folder. How can I implement such function which takes a path (`QString` based input) and tells whether it is a file or folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method [`QFileInfo::isFile()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#isFile) or [`QFileInfo::isDir()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#isDir) to accomplish this.

**Example**:

```
QFileInfo fi("/your/path/string");
if (fi.exists() && fi.isFile())
{
   //Do stuff...
}
```